# Estimating Irreducible error from kappa statistics for medical applications

Tags: machine-learning, classification, error, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

In many medical applications that involve some form of classification the data is annotated by expert humans (e.g. histopathologists, radiologists). This is then taken as the ground-truth. However, it is known that these experts often disagree with each other, and in the absence of a definitive label, we can rarely know who is correct. This disagreement is often quantified by Kappa statistics.

When assessing the performance of a machine learning classifier, it is useful to compare its performance (say using accuracy) to an expert human - this gives us an idea of the irreducible (Bayes) error, which can be a benchmark for classifier performance and give an idea of any degree of under-fitting. However, in the case where there is significant variation in experts' annotations, and with no recourse to the 'true' label, we do not have a direct measure for benchmark performance.

Hence, my question is whether we can use Kappa statistics to say anything useful about the irreducible error of a dataset?